# Angel with 2 missions?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, tanach, malach-angel, maharal, radak

Regarding the angel that Yaacov wrestled, [Radak on Bereshit 32:26](https://www.sefaria.org/Radak_on_Genesis.32.26.2?ven=Eliyahu_Munk,_HaChut_Hameshulash&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says that Yaacov Avinu was hit with limping as a punishment, *midda k'negged midda*, for not trusting in Hashem enough:

> היה לו זה מאת האל להיות בו זה לאות לפי שהיה פושע במחשבתו אחר כמה
> הבטחות אשר עשה עמו האל מדה כנגד מדה
>
> This [the limping] was a sign from G’d, a reprisal of a kind, for the
> doubts he had expressed about the various promises G’d had made him.

This limping was inflicted on Yaacov [by the angel striking him](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.32.26).

The angel also [gave him a new name](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.32.29).

**It seems to me that both of these could easily constitue a mission from Hashem, and they also seem quite distinct.**

Does anyone address if this constitutes the angel having 2 missions? How would Radak deal with that? As we know, [missions are only handed out one at a time, to one angel at a time](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.18.2?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&lang=bi&with=Gur%20Aryeh&lang2=en).

Comment: Why not see it as one mission? If the malakh was intended to facilitate a shift in his thinking - the change in name is to ensure the permanence in the shifted thought process. It would all be one goal - keeping Ya'aqobh from mistaken conception regarding God's promises.

Comment: @Deuteronomy I like where that is going, it would need to be demonstrated how the name change is meant to affect the change of thinking implied by the Radak

Comment: Maybe you can say the new name wasn’t a task from Gd? Meaning, the angel came with one task which was to cripple Yaakov. That was supposed to be it, but then yaakov bested the angel and forced him to bless him or he wouldn’t let him go. Subsequently, the angel gives him a new name as the blessing. So perhaps the new name wasn’t the intended task of the angel, it was more of an improv if you will

Comment: @CuriousYid, I would think the Radaq would subscribe to a more Rambam-like idea of angels, that the angel is the embodiment of the mission. To the rationalists, the reason why no mal'akh can do two jobs is by definition - the Will of G-d being filtered down into the execution of two jobs would be two mal'akhim. Your idea is requiring a more Qabbakistic idea if angel, the kind where if they are not in Hashem's Presence, they have some measure of personal volition and free will,